# Setup and install django-bone

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and Python in general. However, I have been playing around with setting up a Django projects when I came across this: https://github.com/jart/django-bone

Its instructions for setup confuse me. Question:

How do I setup and install django-bone on a Mac?

I have Python and Django all installed and working already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to start out by trying to get all django-bone stuff running on your own.

It seems to require some packages which is not out of the box, like NPM which is a packet handler for nodejs.

**But if you insist. Clone the repo from github. Place it in a suitable directory and execute the bash-script with ./django-bone yourproject**

This will create alot of files (which I guess is to ensure depenacies).

Comment: it is really to see how a project is structured as a learning aid, thank you for your help.